# Finding Statistical Relationship

Tags: regression, biostatistics

I know this is not a typical statistics question. But still I'm posting it here as I don't want to do data manipulation of this problem. I've the data in the following format:

```
Year Yield Input_1 Input_2
2000  1000  100      22
2001  2001  188      43
2002  1665  150      59
```

Now, Input_1 affects yield at monthly level and yield of crop is at yearly level. Suppose, Input_1 is rainfall and we are considering how rainfall affects potato yield at that 
particular year. Suppose rainfall for a particular year is normal, but during potato cultivation season, there's excessive rain. So most of the potato crops died that year. 
So, I can't roll-up the rainfall data (by taking average or sum) from monthly to yearly level in this case.

So, my question is how I can find relationship between monthly input_1 with yearly yield to capture the accurate relationship. I don't want to use dummy variables.

Comment: Simple approach: Add up the rain only for the months that would be relevant for potato yield. A more flexible approach would be to use the rain for each of the months that is relevant for yield each as its own predictor of annual yield.

Comment: @Glen_b: Thanks for your quick reply. There's 2 issue in this case. 1) Suppose I've multiple crop in my analysis. In that case I've to sum up for each plant, which is cumbersome. 2) For some plants, it's not only monthly but weekly rainfall which is important. So the problem I mentioned is much simplified version of the problem I'm working on. But the issue is the same in all cases.

Comment: 1) That should be in your question, but the second option would work by using all 12 each time (as long as you have enough data to support so many predictors). 2) Again, such detail should be in your question -- how are we to guess such details?

Comment: @Glen_b: Sorry for not giving the details. But I tried to make the question as simple as possible.